# Implementing 2 xib in a single view

Tags: objective-c, ipad

In my app for iPad I want to implement 2 xib files in a single view. It should look like a split view but I don't want to use split view. How this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooView" 
                                           owner:self options:nil];
[self.view addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
```

In most cases you'll probably want the first (only?) top level object in the XIB, but there might be cases where you'd want to references different things in the XIB.

The classic example of this is the way we load UITableViewCells. The slight variation here is setting up and using an outlet and loading first item in the XIB straight into the outlet.

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FubarView" owner:self options: nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.fubarViewOutlet];
```

Whatever way you choose to do it, after you add it to a parent view, just set the frame to assign a size and location. Either use the outlet or cast the item from the array as the appropriate class and use it just like other view.

Edit: from your comment request, I'd write something like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewTemp didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if(indexPath.row==0){ 
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CNBViewController" 
                                       owner:self options:nil];
    self.selectedRowView = [array objectAtIndex:0];  // assumes a class variable selectedRowView
    [self.view selectedRowView];
    // newView.frame = CGRectMake(........);
  }
}
```

Comment: I m trying this code but I dont know How to set this in my app. could you please help me?
I mean in the first half of the ipad screen i want table view and its didselectObjectAtIndex:0 I want detail view to be shown on the next half.

Comment: For this, I'd suggest creating a UIViewController with a XIB (just check off the box when creating the UIViewController). Then go into the XIB, and create your table which maybe covers half the screen.
From there add your UITableView delegate/datasource. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: insert the code which loads the second XIB. Do an addSubview: to add the newly loaded view (from the second XIB) into the primary XIB. Be sure to set the frame of the new XIB, since the size might be 0,0 (so you won't be able to see it)

Comment: This is the code which I have used but it entirely taking me to the another page



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewTemp didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

if(indexPath.row==0){ 
self.title=@"Create New Brochure"; 
CNBViewController *xib1 = [[CNBViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CNBViewController" bundle:nil]; 

//[self.view removeFromSuperview]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:xib1 animated:YES]; 

[xib1 release]; 
}



Can you help me the code through which I can load the another xib on the same page.